# Levensthein distance with different values for vowels

Tags: python-3.x

I need this function to return the Levensthein distance of two strings. Normally, insertion , deletion, and substitution all have a cost of 1. But in this case I need the cost of insertion and deletion of a vowel to be not 1 but 0.5.

Here's my code so far:

```
def levenstheindist(word1, word2):

    if len(word1) > len(word2):
        word1, word2 = word2, word1

    distances = range(len(word1) + 1)
    for it2, char2 in enumerate(word2):
        if char2 in 'aeiuo':
            distances_ = [it2 + 0.5]
        if char2 not in 'aeiuo':
            distances_ = [it2 + 1]
        for it1, char1 in enumerate(word1):
            if char1 == char2:
                distances_.append(distances[it1])
            if char1 in 'aeiuo':
                distances_.append(distances[it1 + 0.5])
            if char1 not in 'aeiuo':
                distances_.append(1 + min((distances[it1], distances[it1 + 1], distances_[-1])))

        distances = distances_

    return distances[-1]
```

The output for the strings 'aaax' and 'x' should be 1.5, but as of now my function returns 2.5. What am I doing wrong?